# Unauthorized error flashing after launching bigcommerce store on localhost

Tags: bigcommerce

Trying to do set up on localhost from live bigcommerce store.
Followed by installation guide as mentioned here: 
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/prerequisites-windows

After

stencil start

command in cmd prompt its redirected to localhost:3000 in the browser with error Unauthorized and none of the store files get fetched inside my base theme on local machine.
please find an attachment. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDSU7.jpg)

Do am I missing anything?

Comment: If OAuth clientId and accessToken entries are absent, and you instead see legacy entries reading username and token, no editing is required. Skip directly ahead to Initialize the Theme.
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/initializing-stencil#legacy